# When does web.config get validated?

Tags: iis, web-config

As for IIS, I have a PHP app, and I am using `web.config` for configuration.

When I change settings in `web.config`, shall I restart the server? or just refresh my webpage and expect settings to take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly restart server. Web.config is special file, any changes in it are watched FileWatcher and app pool is restarted automatically when you do changes in this file. So your app pool restarts on following things.

- Any changes in web.config
- Any changes in machine.config
- Any changes in global.asax
- Anything changes in bin directory or it's sub-directories

Comment: Pretty much correct, except that the AppPool itself is not restarted, the process remains the same. In asp.net the AddDomain within the pool is restarted, I'm not sure about PHP, but I guess the main thread for the PHP engine is restarted,

Comment: Note that IIS 7 and above monitors web.config for <system.webServer> section. That applies to PHP sites.